# Sportfire cross table coloring scheme

Tags: visualization, spotfire, spotfire-analyst, crosstable

I have a cross table with programs on y axis, activities on x axis and I am displaying dates in the cross table. I want to color the cells (dates) based on values from a different column in the data table (Status) that is not displayed in the cross table.
For example - All dates in 2022 should be green (based on status complete) and all dates in 2023 should ne yellow (based on status planned).
Note that these dates are in MM/DD/YYYY format

How do I do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The feature to color by another column was added in version 11.2.

Open the properties for the cross table and go to the color tab. Check the 'Color the grouping using another expression'. Specify the expression to color by in the field below the checkbox, see the attached image.

[image]